# Giving public access to root directory of svn

Tags: svn, apache, module, directory, root

i was wondering if it is possible to let people access subversion root directory trough apache and 'dav_svn' module. Now i can only access only repositories that are 1 level lover than root directory (*"svn/game" "svn/something" but not "svn/"*).
My **httpd.conf**:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath C:/SVN
    AuthzSVNAccessFile C:/SVN/users
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repository"
    AuthUserFile C:/SVN/svn-auth-file
</Location>
```

Now, when i try to access root directory it asks me for a user name and a password.

Help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are asking for is access to the Subversion repositories list, which is disabled by default.

Try setting `SVNListParentPath on` in the location block of your httpd.conf:

```
...
    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    SVNParentPath C:/SVN
    AuthzSVNAccessFile C:/SVN/users
...
```

It is also important to note that Subversion clients cannot talk to the repository list, and this can only be seen through a web browser connecting to the "root" svn path.